Dynamic fields in django admin from __init__ form method
I have some models:

class Variation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class VariationOption(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value


class BaseProduct(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    variations = models.ManyToManyField(Variation, blank=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    base_product = models.ForeignKey(BaseProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    variation_options = models.ManyToManyField(VariationOption, null=True, blank=True)



an admin form where i dynamically add fields in init method:
class ProductAdminInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ['variation_options']

    def __init__(self, base_product, *args, **kwargs):

        super(ProductAdminInlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if base_product:
            self.base_product = base_product
            variations = self.base_product.variations.all()
            for variation in variations:
                field_name = f'variation_{variation.id}'
                self.fields[field_name] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                    queryset=VariationOption.objects.filter(variation=variation),
                    required=True,
                    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                    label=variation.name
                )

here is my admin models:

class ProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Product
    exclude = ['variation_options']
    form = ProductAdminInlineForm


class BaseProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = BaseProduct
    list_display = ['__str__']
    inlines = [ProductInline]

    def get_formset_kwargs(self, request, obj, inline, prefix, **kwargs):
        return {
            **super().get_formset_kwargs(request, obj, inline, prefix),
            'form_kwargs': {"base_product": obj},
        }

I'm trying to retrieve dynamic fields that i declare in ProductAdminInlineForm init method in the admin page but it look like ProductInline doesn't call init to retrieve form fields.
How can i achieve this ?
I tried to overrides get_fields and get_fieldset method in ProductInline class:
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = super(ProductInline, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
        if obj is not None:
            variations = obj.variations.all()
            for variation in variations:
                field_name = f'variation_{variation.id}'
                field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                    queryset=VariationOption.objects.filter(variation=variation),
                    required=True,
                    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                    label=variation.name
                )
                fieldsets[0][1]['fields'].append(field_name)
        return fieldsets

but it didn't work because field is not present in Product Model:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 688, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1889, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1747, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1820, in _changeform_view
    formsets, inline_instances = self._create_formsets(
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 2257, in _create_formsets
    for FormSet, inline in self.get_formsets_with_inlines(*get_formsets_args):
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 907, in get_formsets_with_inlines
    yield inline.get_formset(request, obj), inline
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 2436, in get_formset
    return inlineformset_factory(self.parent_model, self.model, **defaults)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1322, in inlineformset_factory
    FormSet = modelformset_factory(model, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1036, in modelformset_factory
    form = modelform_factory(
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 642, in modelform_factory
    return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 321, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (variation_2, variation_1) specified for Product
[23/Aug/2024 07:56:06] "GET /admin/shop_app/baseproduct/9/change/ HTTP/1.1" 500 160839
/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/oak_project/shop_app/admin.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
shop_app.Product.variation_options: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
August 23, 2024 - 08:00:53
Django version 4.2.13, using settings 'oak_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Internal Server Error: /admin/shop_app/baseproduct/9/change/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 688, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1889, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1747, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1820, in _changeform_view
    formsets, inline_instances = self._create_formsets(
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 2257, in _create_formsets
    for FormSet, inline in self.get_formsets_with_inlines(*get_formsets_args):
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 907, in get_formsets_with_inlines
    yield inline.get_formset(request, obj), inline
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 2436, in get_formset
    return inlineformset_factory(self.parent_model, self.model, **defaults)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1322, in inlineformset_factory
    FormSet = modelformset_factory(model, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1036, in modelformset_factory
    form = modelform_factory(
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 642, in modelform_factory
    return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
  File "/home/kara/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.oak_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 321, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (variation_2, variation_1) specified for Product


